# Server-side object in PHP is empty when returned to client

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json, web-applications

I have a server-side PHP script that generates an object containing aggregated data from a database.  The script builds the object, encodes it to JSON and returns it to the client, where the original request was made by this jQuery.ajax call :

```
$.ajax({
        async: false,
        url: 'scripts/getDataforUser.php?firstName=' + _firstName+ '&lastName=' + _lastName,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(result) {
          //Do stuff with 'result' object
          //result object sometimes comes back empty
        },
        error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
             displayError('An error occurred while fetching data');
             return;
          }
      });
```

My problem is that I occasionally get an empty result object returned, this seems to happen with larger requests, but is seemingly random so it's been a challenge to trace the cause.  I'm using Zend Server with Eclipse as my IDE, I've debugged the script several times to confirm that A) there is data, and B) the result object is getting properly encoded to JSON using `json_encode($data, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT)` on the PHP side.

Again, this error only seems to occur with larger objects, since I can see data when debugging the getDataforUser.php script directly, I'm focused on the client-side and seeing if there's some error on being received on the Javascript side.

I'm not sure at this point what's getting lost in translation from the server to the client.  Is the issue with how I'm JSON encoding the object in PHP?  How I'm calling the server to get that encoded object?  A combination of both?  Or is there something more fundamental that I'm missing?

**UPDATE:**

Hi Ben, as stated in my comment, one detail I neglected to include in my original post that may provide some insight into the issue, is that a fellow developer running the same URL on his local dev server gets a null object returned, while I just get an object with empty properties.  Could our local server's PHP configuration be the issue?  In my PHP.ini file, I have the following settings for my resource limits, which I expected would be more than enough in this case.

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Resource Limits ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

max_execution_time = 600     ; Maximum execution time of each script, in seconds
max_input_time = 180 ; Maximum amount of time each script may spend parsing request data
memory_limit = 128M      ; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (128MB)
```

From debugging the script directly, the script doesn't take more than 600 seconds to execute this query.  It parses the request data well within the time limit, and no errors are thrown regarding memory exhaustion.

**Update 2:**

My development environment is running the Apache web server.

**Update 3:**

@Ben - I took a quick look at the [Apache core documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#timeout) and the Timeout directive's default is 300 seconds, although as I mention above, I am using Zend Server CE as my dev server ( it sits on top of Apache), so it may have its own default Timeout directive that it sets in its internal Apache configuration.  Again, I'll have to check.

Also just to clarify, my partner on this software project is having the same issue, only instead of getting back an empty object, he gets back null.

**Update 4:**

Ok, I was doing some extensive testing and validation on my local web server.  One detail that is relevant is that the database I'm querying is hosted on MS SQL Server, I'm using the SQL Server Native Client PHP Driver as my database abstraction layer.  Anyway, after reviewing the logs I see that the query for data is timing out with the SQL Native Client reporting the following:

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 08S01
            [SQLSTATE] => 08S01
            [1] => 258
            [code] => 258
            [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]TCP Provider: Timeout error [258]. 
            [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]TCP Provider: Timeout error [258]. 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 08S01
            [SQLSTATE] => 08S01
            [1] => 258
            [code] => 258
            [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Communication link failure
            [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Communication link failure
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 08S01
            [SQLSTATE] => 08S01
            [1] => -2147467259
            [code] => -2147467259
            [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Communication link failure
            [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Communication link failure
        )
```

This seems to be the primary source of empty data in the result object, I'm still searching for information on this error, I'm not sure if the timeout setting I need to update is in the SQL Server Native Client itself or in the database.  More investigation is needed.

**Update 5:**

I've ruled out the database timeout, the remote connection timeout setting is set to 600 seconds.  I've read throughout online that using the PDO ODBC driver is preferred as timeouts don't seem to be an issue with it.  I'm going to try that and see if it resolves this timeout issue.

**Final Update Resolution:**

Ok, so switching to the PDO driver seems to have resolved my timeout issue, I verified the PDO driver working on both our local dev machines and our staging server.  I'm still not sure what would be causing the SQL Server Native Client to time out when using the SQLSRV driver.  For now I'll mark the main issue as resolved since I'm now getting back data.  Thanks Ben D and everyone else for your support.

Comment: Does it return an empty object or does it just return nothing? How long (approx) does it take for the server to generate and serve these larger objects?

Comment: [Firebug for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/firebug/) let's you see exactly what is being sent back to your browser as well as how long it took.

Comment: @Ben D - in my case, the object is simply empty.  However, one of my fellow developers running the same URL query gets nothing.

Comment: it could be you can send/post only limited size object via POST or GET unless you specify it as <form enctype="multipart/form-data">, for example if you are uploading files (this case bigger data set) you need to add above to the form so that it sends the data in chunks not in one.

Comment: Question 2: what's your web server (apache, iis, etc)?

Comment: @Ben D - My local web server is running Apache. I have to leave now for an appointment, but I will continue to monitor this thread and update as necessary.  Thanks again for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

There are three obvious sources of the problem: it's either a problem returning the ajax request, or with the PHP script that is being called, or with webserver serving the php result. I'm guessing it's a PHP problem, but just to be thorough:

It's possible that your `$.ajax()` request is timing out because even though jquery has no timeout default, different browsers seem to set their own timeouts on ajax requests][1](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php). This may be further complicated by the `async: false` setting, though I'm not sure. I'm guessing this isn't it, as I think that browser-timeouts would trigger the ajax error clause and you note in comments that someone was able to reproduce directly from the URL, but it's easy to make sure using firebug (or equivalent) and watching the traffic.

The likelihood that it's a PHP problem is much higher. A few things to check: 1. That the PHP script isn't either timing out (`max_execution_time` in ini file) or hitting a memory cap (`memory_limit` in ini). Also make sure that you're not accidentally trying to encode non-utf8 characters and you're just happening to hit them in large objects (in which case `json_encode()` will return `null`). Try turning on errors, see if any are generated, and also **try running [json_last_error()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php)** to see if there was a problem creating the json string.

Lastly, it's possible that Apache is the problem. Your request looks pretty tiny, so I doubt it's hitting any request url limits, but it's possible that the web server is timing out while waiting for php to create the object... check what your `TimeOut` value is in your http.conf file.

Comment: Thanks Ben, I'm in school now, but I'll be back at work tomorrow.  I'll go through each of these items in the morning and give an update then.  Thanks again for your input.

Answer (score -1):

Don't pass the GET parameters through the URL. use the "data" property instead:

```
$.ajax({.... data: { firstName: "bob", lastName: "smith" } });
```

Comment: While I agree with your sentiment, I don't see how this addresses the problem.